# Using only Django 2.2 ORM

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-orm

I want to use Django with python3 to connect to my Postgresql database. I need only ORM modules of Django. My question is that what is the best project structure to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It varies with programmer and project requirements. Typically I prefer to create an admin app for the CMS projects and build the admin panel structure inside that app. For The main site, static content, media files, I prefer it to be in the root project directory.

So the folder structure is something like...

```
Project
|__rootApp(Includes settings.py)
|__admin(app)
|  |__users
|  |__roles
|  |__permissions
|__users
|__posts
|__comments
|__app1
|__app2
.
.
.
|__static
|__media
|__templates
|__manage.py
```

Comment: Then use the app for that purpose and keep it in the root folder. No issues in keeping anywhere unless you are not messing up with the path and URLs.